# How to Allow Keyboard Shortcuts to Navigate CME Drop-down Menus

Tags: 2011, cme, 2009

I'm able to navigate *some* drop-down menus by typing the first letter of an option in SDL Tridion 2011. This seems to work for out-of-the-box options like Schema Type, Field Type, and anything that's already part of the Content Manager Explorer (CME).

I can navigate a schema drop-down by typing letters in SDL Tridion 2009, but I can't seem to get the same behavior with 2011. For example, I'd like to be able to press "C" and have the CME select "Code" or "A" for "Article" (never mind the poor schema naming conventions in the screenshot).

[image: Can I press "C" to jump to "Code"?]

I'd like to be able to navigate all CME drop-downs by letter; is this possible? What am I missing, and how might I enable this through configuration or an extension?

Comment: You mean unable to navigate drop-down's. Right?

Comment: I updated the question to clarify that I can navigate some drop-downs (mainly "built-in" drop-down choices) using the first letter of the options. I want to be able to do the same with schema and template selections.

Comment: It would be nice for user lists in the PubQ also

Comment: Its nice to have, all Tridion dropdown's with navigation facility.

Comment: @AlvinReyes: Its better, you make this question more generic and which solves all tridion dropdown's navigation problems.

Comment: Good ideas--I updated the question. However, I think 1) it was fairly general in the question itself and 2) I wanted to share specific examples that I could confirm (rather than assuming which drop-downs worked and which didn't). I didn't feel like checking each drop-down (there's a lot, btw). :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lists where it works are standard select controls and your browser does the keyboard support for you. In the custom drop-down list controls (e.g. the ones with icons in them), this keyboard support was missing.

This shortcoming has been fixed in Tridion 2013.

Comment: +1 and accepted. Nice, thanks for explaining the difference and when it'll get fixed. I'll check how 2013 does this, but any thoughts on how we'd do this for 2011--a CME GUI extension?

Comment: There's no easy way to do it in 2011. You would have to patch the List control -- not something I would recommend.

Comment: Ok, works for me. I haven't seen to many requests for this from others and it's good to see this addressed in the next version.