# IE 10 Unexpected Drop-down List Behavior

Tags: cme, 2013

As a follow-up to "[How to Allow Keyboard Shortcuts to Navigate CME Drop-down Menus](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/199/46)" I can see "navigate-by-first-letter" working nicely in SDL Tridion 2013's Content Manager Explorer (CME).

In IE 10 (10.0.9200.16660 / Update Versions: [10.0.8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2862772)), I had the following strange behavior, which turned out to be a Compatibility View Setting (answer below).

**IE 10**:

- Pressing a starting letter not in the list will select the next item (even if the letter did not match)
- Pressing a starting letter in the list multiple times will loop through each item, but then select the next item in the list as well
- Pressing other characters also changed the dropdown

**Chrome** and **Firefox** acted as I’d expect:

- Pressing a letter not in the list will leave the same item selected
- Pressing a letter multiple times will cycle through all matching items and eventually loop to the first item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue went away by removing Compatibility View.

Specifically, I have the CMS in Local Intranet Zone per the documentation (which also solved [Blocked CSS files for Session Preview only in Internet Explorer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/2313/46)). In this case, I had to uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"  Tools > Compatibility View Settings, close the component and try again.

Using IE's developer tools (F12) reminded me the setting was wrong. You'll see something like:

- `HTML1201: cms-domain is a website you've added to Compatibility View.`
- `HTML1202: http://cms-domain/WebUI/item.aspx?tcm=16 is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked.`